# Обратная геокодировка

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите, как сделать обратную геокодировку (6000) адресов. Файл - Excel. Координаты перевести в адреса. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, обратите внимание, что условия использования API Яндекс.Карт не разрешают сохранение данных, полученных средствами API. Полученные данные должны быть показаны на карте Яндекса. Бесплатно использовать API можно только в проектах с открытым доступом. Полные условия доступны вот здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/

В целом для решения вашей задачи можно использовать API Геокодера, вот примеры: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/examples/geocoder_examples-docpage/#geocoder_examples__coordinates

Также есть примеры с использованием JavaScript API, вот тут подробнее: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/geocode-docpage/